# Only first word of string appearing in HTML form when using string-reference

Tags: php, html, string, forms

I'm having a problem with a HTML form and php.

I'm trying to make the default-value of a form-text field to be a pre-defined string. For this I'm using a reference. However, whenever I try to place a string into the form using PHP or references in any kind shape or form, only the first word gets added.

Here is a picture to describe the situation:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening, and/or a way to work around this issue?

Actual code:

```
<?php 
    Echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Address\" value=\"one two three\"><br>";
?>

<?php 
    $str ="one two three";
    Echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Address\" value=" . $str . "><br>";
?>

<input type="text" name="Address" value=<?php echo "one two three";?>><br>
<input type="text" name="Address" value=<?php $str = "one two three"; echo $str;?>><br>
<input type="text" name="Address" value="one two three"><br>
```

Comment: If you "view source" and look at the generate HTML it will be quite obvious

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't quote the echoed words.
Basically you do this:

```
<input type="text" value=one two three />
```

But you need to do that:

```
<input type="text" value="one two three" />
```

Just add "" around the PHP.

BTW: You need to escape these if you don't want to get XSSed. These attacks are quite scary. Read about it here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: Look at the code syntax highlighting. That alone would tell you what's wrong with it. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem was  the `quotes` when you was doing the echo on the php, you need to simple-quote it to make it works.

Html was understanding that `two` and `three` was additional parameters of the `<input>` because it wasnt quoted on the resulting html.

**Use this way:**

```
<?php 
    Echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Address\"     value=\"one two three\"><br>";
?>

<?php 
    $str ="one two three";
    Echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Address\"     value=" . $str . "><br>";
?>

<input type="text" name="Address" value='<?php echo "one two three";?>'><br>
<input type="text" name="Address" value='<?php $str = "one two three"; echo $str;?>'><br>
<input type="text" name="Address" value="one two three"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you dont set it in "" or '' marks for the html.

The 2. Line: ...\"Address\" value=" . $str . ">
...."; 
for example outputs for the value attribute: value=one two three
The interpreter now thinks two and three are propertys and not part of value. 
Same with the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this value attribute of input type having a string with whitespace. HTML treat it as separate attributes of input text.

To resolve this problem, u can use single quote at begining and end of value attribute.
Look this example. Hope you will like this. I just modified your code.

```
<?php
   echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Address\" value=\"one two three\"><br>";
?>

<?php
   $str ="one two three";
   echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Address\" value='" . $str . "'><br>";
?>

<input type="text" name="Address" value='<?php echo "one two three";?>'><br>
<input type="text" name="Address" value='<?php $str = "one two three"; echo $str;?>'><br>
<input type="text" name="Address" value="one two three"><br>
```

In this case it will get One Two Three in every textbox.