# Update Text updating in database but after click update, it return to only 1 text

Tags: php, html

I have worked on an update form not from scratch, but on updating my text to database, for example I have field with text *BSc Engineering*, on click update with a new text with *BSc Information System*, it updates in database but on display form it shows only the *BSc*.. all text separated with a space always shows the first word..

Why?

An extract of my Line of code

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=char name=stud_NAME value=" .$row['stud_NAME'] . "> </td>"; 

echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=submit value=update > </td>";
```

Comment: Please post your code for `update`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only first word of string appearing in HTML form when using string-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335777/only-first-word-of-string-appearing-in-html-form-when-using-string-reference) - Also never call anything in a form `name="submit"` since it breaks the submit event handler of the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes on the input attributes.

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type='char' name='stud_NAME' value='" .$row['stud_NAME'] . "'/> </td>"; 

echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='update'/> </td>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Works